# I am trying to create time converter using switch statement in c language, but its not working

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

int main() {
  char question_unit, answer_unit;
  int month, days, time_value, time;
  float answer;
  printf("enter the given time value : ");
  scanf("%d", &time_value);
  printf("Months  -->a \n");
  printf("Days    -->b \n");
  printf("Hours   -->c \n");
  printf("Minute  -->d \n");
  printf("Seconds -->e \n");
  printf("enter the given time unit (as per above notation): ");
  scanf("%c", &question_unit);
  printf("enter the required time unit (as per above notation): ");
  scanf("%c", &answer_unit);
  switch (question_unit) {
    case 'a':
      time = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * time_value;
      break;
    case 'b':
      time = 24 * 60 * 60 * time_value;
      break;
    case 'c':
      time = 60 * 60 * time_value;
      break;
    case 'd':
      time = 60 * time_value;
      break;
    case 'e':
      time = time_value;
      break;
    default:
      printf("You enter wrong given unit\n");
      break;
  }
  switch (answer_unit) {
    case 'a':
      answer = time / (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
      break;
    case 'b':
      answer = time / (24 * 60 * 60);
      break;
    case 'c':
      answer = time / (60 * 60);
      break;
    case 'd':
      answer = time / 60;
      break;
    case 'e':
      answer = time;
      break;
    default:
      printf("You enter wrong asked unit\n");
      break;
  }
  printf("%d --convered--> %f", time_value, answer);
  getch();
  return 1;
}
```

When I am running this code. The `scanf()` does not work properly. It does not take any value.

Comment: OK, we can't even help you formatting it because even the plain text looks like a mess.

Comment: identing plz its barelly readable,
also surround the code with ``

Comment: In addition to formatting the code to make it readable please also show the exact and complete run log - give the exact input, actual result and expected result.

Comment: The problem is likely to be the use of `%c` in `scanf` (a common problem). `%c` only reads one character. You are likely entering a letter followed by ENTER/newline (\n). The `%c` will only consume the letter and leave the newline in the input. The next `scanf` will then immedialy read the newline and thus appear to skip your next input.

Comment: To create a code block, use 3 backticks, not single quotes. (The backtick is to the left of the `1` key on my keyboard.) To fix the code, you should [edit] the question, delete the existing code, and copy/paste between the backticks.

Comment: stranger,  `scanf()` worked properly, just not the way you expect.  After `scanf("%c", &question_unit);`, `question_unit` has the value of `'\n'`.  Replace `"%c"` with `" %c"`  (note the space) in 2 places.

Comment: Note: `time / (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);` is integer division with an integer quotient.  Did you want a floating point division?   If so, make at least one of the `/` operands a floating point.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c", &question_unit);` only asks for one character. `scanf("%c\n", &question_unit);` will require an enter, so that the next question is asked.